# Negative squats

Tags: exercise, strength, strength-training, squats, legs

Can doing negative squats with a belt, going down slowly then using arms to go back up be used to break a squat stalls? If not, are there any other benefit on using negative squats?

Comment: Eccentric movements are always useful for strengthening muscles. The muscles strengthened there might not always help the entirety of an exercise however.

Comment: Following a proper progressive overload program is the best way to break through plateaus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have been stuck at a given *Max Squat* weight for several months and you are trying to increase that *Max Squat* weight, anything different is good to break that stagnant environment.

- 1 legged squats
- wide stance squats
- narrow stance squats
- squat down farther (use lighter weight when going down farther)
- from the bottom, jump instead of your normal push
- alternate your squat days with 8 sets of 10 at heavy (but not your max) weight

If your body becomes adjusted to something, it's time to change. Never let your body figure out what your mind has planned for it. :)